# SSRS Avg Function in Multiple Scopes

Tags: reporting-services, scope, average

I have a tablix with 2 groups on the columns (year and month) and 1 group on the rows (shops).

For the value of every month the column shall be filled with a color that is dependent on the average. But this average should be just for this shop and the current year.

So if i just do:

```
=AVG(Fields!Value.Value)
```

it will give me the average by shop and month.
But if i set the year as scope:

```
=AVG(Fields!Value.Value,"Year")
```

it will give me the average for ALL shops of the current year group.

Is there any way to get the average by year and shop as wanted??

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column which is scoped outside of the `Month` group but inside the `Year` group, then just use `AVG(Fields!Value.Value)`. Your matrix should look like this:

[image]

It will produce something like this:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
but the problem with that is, that the columns are specified by the customer and he does not want to have it like this.
and the other thing is, that i need the value in the tooltip of the avg columns in the month group

Comment: @TimDoring, I think you can do that using custom code. Let me know if you are here and need details.

Comment: meanwhile i just solved it in the stored procedure that delivers the data for the tablix.
but if you know how to solve it inside ssrs i would be pleased to see how :)